# what is the fastest method to check if given array has array or non-array or both values?

Tags: php, arrays

We gave a given array which can be in 4 states.

array has values that are:

- only arrays
- only non-arrays
- both array and non array
- array has no values

Comment: Keys cannot be arrays: *A key may be either an integer or a string* (http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php). Do you mean values?

Comment: Please add a sample array to explain what you mean.

Comment: yes, your are right, I meant values

Comment: Do you need to determine between the states? Or just need a true if any or all four states are met?

Comment: I need to determine, that is 1,2,3,4th state.

Comment: Btw is this homework? Sounds like such...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some precalculation:

```
function isArray($reducedValue, $currentValue) {
    // boolean value is converted to 0 or 1
    return $reducedValue + is_array($currentValue);
}

$number_of_arrays = array_reduce($array, 'isArray', 0);
```

Then the different states can be evaluated as follows:

> 1. only arrays
>
>    ```
>    count($array) == $number_of_arrays
>    ```
> 2. only non-arrays
>
>    ```
>    $number_of_arrays == 0
>    ```
> 3. both array and non array keys
>
>    ```
>    count($array) != $number_of_arrays
>    ```
> 4. array has no keys
>
>    ```
>     empty($array);
>    ```

So you just need to write a function that returns the appropriate state.

Reference: [`in_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), [`array_reduce`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php), [`empty`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 2):

Considering than an array-key can only be a numerical or string value *(and not an array)*, I suppose you want to know about array-values ?

If so, you'll have to loop over your array, testing, for each element, if it's an array or not, keeping track of what's been found -- see the [**`is_array`**](https://www.php.net/is_array) function, about that.

Then, when you've tested all elements, you'll have to test if you found arrays, and/or non-array.

Something like this, I suppose, might do the trick :

```
$has_array = false;
$has_non_array = false;

foreach ($your_array as $element) {
    if (is_array($element)) {
        $has_array = true;
    } else {
        $has_non_array = true;
    }
}

if ($has_array && $has_non_array) {
    // both
} else {
    if ($has_array) {
        // only arrays
    } else {
        // only non-array
    }
}
```

*(Not tested, but the idea should be there)*

This portion of code should work for the three first points you asked for.

To test for *"array has no value"*, The fastest way is to use the [**`empty()`**](https://www.php.net/empty) language construct before the loop -- and only do the loop if the array is not empty, to avoid any error.

You could also count the number of elements in the array, using the [**`count()`**](http://fr.php.net/count)  function, and test if it's equal to `0`, BTW.